# when I enter localhost:8080 in the browser, it gets redirected to http://localhost:8080/apex/f?p=4950:1

Tags: oracle-apex, apache-tomee

I have tomee installed and Oracle Express, and I switched the port of Oracle Express apex to 3010, but now when I try to enter my webapp on http://localhost:8080/ I get redirected to http://localhost:8080/apex/f?p=4950:1 and can't access my deployed webapp

Strangely enough, accessing it through http://127.0.0.1:8080 works perfectly.

Where is the redirection coming from?

Comment: I found the same thing after running oracle XE and trying to access it at port 8080. It would appear oracle XE sends a 301 redirect to the default apex app id which gets cached by the browser.  Clearing my browser cache sorted it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Those are two different issues:

1. To access your app replace the 4950 with the ID from your app (you
   may need to undo the changes to get the ID in case you didn't pay
   attention to the ID when you created it)
2. Redirection: Unless you
   have a explicit entry in your hostname, DNS or NIS your routing may
   be inconsistent or glitchy and based on your computer and browser's
   cache. You may not want to use localhost until then, stick to an IP
   address
3. You can specify the app number 4500 to access the Application Builder and from there check the ID for your deployed application.
   Like this: http://127.0.0.1/apex/f?p=4550:1